# The correct mysql statement for linking countys to the only locations with document

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 3 tables in the a db.

1 location (location_id, county_id, name)

2 county (county_id, name)

3 document (document_id, document_type, location_id, title, text)

The sql statement I have:

```
SELECT d.document_id, d.title, l.name AS location_name

FROM  document d 
  INNER JOIN location l ON d.location_id=l.location_id
WHERE d.document_type = 1 AND d.title LIKE '%foo%'
```

I need the document `title and id`, the location `name and location_id`, and the county  `name and county_id` to be returned.

The question is how can I select the county names and county_id for only the locations I have a in this result and not for all locations in location table.

If I do another `INNER JOIN county c ON l.county_id=c.county_id`, then the query is taking to long, with adding counties for all locations (There are 13.000 locations in the table).

Comment: Another join is the answer to your question. If it takes a long time to run the query, then add appropriate indexes.

Comment: I was thinking more something like a sub `SELECT DISTINCT (d.location_id) ` and joining in counties only for these locations... But I cant get a grip on this ....

Comment: Do you mean `l.name like '%foo%'`? I don't see a `name` column in the document table.

Answer (score 0):

select * from country where country_id in (
SELECT country_id

FROM  document d 
  INNER JOIN location l ON d.location_id=l.location_id
WHERE d.document_type = 1 AND d.title LIKE '%foo%')